# Scheme - How do I get each list in a list that's not made up of more lists

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

```
   (define (walk-list lst fun)                       ;;walk-list(list, fun)
    (if (not(null? lst))                             ;;IF the list isn't NULL
      (begin
        (if (list? lst)                              ;;&& the list is actually a list ,       THEN{
          (begin  
            (if (equal? (car lst) '())              ;;IF the first element in the list is empty
              (fun lst)                              ;;THEN call the function on the list (funct is supose to get each word)
            (if (not (null? lst))                    ;;ELSE IF the first item isn't a list 
              (begin                                 ;;{         
                (walk-list (car lst) fun)            ;;walk-list((car lst),fun) 
                (walk-list (cdr lst) fun)))))))))    ;;walk-list((cdr lst),fun)
(walk-list test-document display)                    ;;walk through the list with the given document
```

The will look something like this:

```
(define test-document '(
                       ((h e l l o));;paragraph1
                       ((t h i s)(i s)(t e s t));;paragraph2
                       ))
```

I'm trying to get each individual word into the document have a function applied to it. Where is says (fun list). But the function is never called.

Comment: Can you show a call to this procedure and the expected output?

Comment: The function _is_ called, but you're not building an output list with the results

Comment: The function prints it. I'm going to change it to display, it still doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off. `begin` is if you need to do more than one expression. The first expression then needs to have side effects or else it's just a waste of processing power.

Ie.

```
(begin 
  (display "hello") ; display is a side effect
  (something-else))
```

When you don't have more than one expression `begin` isn't needed. `if` has 3 parts. They are:

```
(if predicate-expression    ; turnas into something true or #f (the only false value)
    consequent-expression   ; when predicate-expression evalautes to anything but #f
    alternative-expression) ; when predicate-expression evaluates to #f this is done
```

You should ident your code properly. Here is the code idented with DrRacket IDE, with reduncant `begin` removed and missing alternative-expressions added so you see where they return:

```
(define (walk-list lst fun)                       ;;walk-list(list, fun)
  (if (not (null? lst))                           ;;IF the list isn't NULL
      (if (list? lst)                             ;; && the list is actually a list ,       THEN{
          (if (equal? (car lst) '())              ;; IF the first element in the list is empty
              (fun lst)                           ;; THEN call the function on the list (funct is supose to get each word)
              (if (not (null? lst))               ;; ELSE IF the first item isn't a list 
                  (begin                          ;; Here begin is needed        
                    (walk-list (car lst) fun)     ;; walk-list((car lst),fun) 
                    (walk-list (cdr lst) fun))    ;; walk-list((cdr lst),fun)
                  'undfined-return-1))            ;; stop recursion, return undefined value
          'undefined-return-2)                    ;; stop recursion, return undefined value
      'undefined-return-3))                       ;; stop recursion, return undefined value
```

So when does `(fun lst)` get called? Never! There is no `()` in any `car` in `(((h e l l o))((t h i s) (i s) (t e s t)))` and `(equal? (car lst) '())` which is `(null? (car lst))` will always be #f. Since we know `(not (null? lst))` is #t so it will walk `car` and `cdr` where either `'undefined-return-2` or `'undefined-return-3` will be evaluated and the procedure stops when everything is visited and nothing processed.

You haven't shown what `(walk-list test-document display)` should have displayed but I make a wild guess that you want it for every element except pairs and null, thus I would have written this like this:

```
(accumulate-tree test-document display (lambda (a d) 'return) '())
```

`accumulate-tree` you'll find in [this SICP handout](http://www.aduni.org/courses/sicp/courseware/handouts/Trees.scm). It demonstrates many uses for it as well. For completeness I'll supply it here:

```
(define (accumulate-tree tree term combiner null-value)
  (cond ((null? tree) null-value)
        ((not (pair? tree)) (term tree))
        (else (combiner 
               (accumulate-tree (car tree) 
                                term
                                combiner
                                null-value)
               (accumulate-tree (cdr tree)
                                term
                                combiner
                                null-value)))))
```

Judging from you code you are an Algol programmer learning your first Lisp. I advice you to look at the [SICP videoes and book](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/).

Comment: @PhilipRego What do you mean? `(accumulate-tree test-document display (lambda (a d) 'return) '())` prints "hellothisistest" and `(accumulate-tree test-document (lambda (x) 1) + 0)` evaluates to the number of atoms. IMO that is not nothing.